# when condition with ignore case in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, if-statement, conditional-statements, case, kotlin-when

I know we can write `if, else if, else if` with a ignore case.

```
if (someString.equals("otherString", ignoreCase = true)) {
}
```

I am very curious about this, how to write a when(in Java it is a switch) condition with ignoring the case.

Comment: when(someString.toLower()) { "bla" -> ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Translate strings to lower (or upper) case:

   ```
   when (someString.toLowerCase()) {
       "otherString1".toLowerCase() -> { /*...*/ }
       "otherString2".toLowerCase() -> { /*...*/ }
   }
   ```
2. Directly use `equals` method:

   ```
    when {
        someString.equals("otherString1", ignoreCase = true) -> { /*...*/ }
        someString.equals("otherString2", ignoreCase = true) -> { /*...*/ }
    }
   ```